# JScrollPanes in JInternalFrames for right to left component orientations - Java bug?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, right-to-left, jinternalframe

So I have created some demo code, see below.

What I am seeing is that if a JScrollPane is within a JInternalFrame and component orientation is set to right-to-left, when minmising the frame, the scroll bar stays to the left of the content. I would expect, seeing as RtL, that it would stay to the right of the content, which is true if the scroll pane is not added to an internal frame (see both frames - one appears behind the other in the demo).

So is this a Java bug or have I forgotten to do something?

Here's the demo code:

```
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class JScrollBarTest
{
    public static void main(String[] a)
    {
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        runInternalFrameDemo();
        runNormalDemo();
    }

    private static void runInternalFrameDemo()
    {
        // Frame...
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Internal Frame Demo");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Desktop pane...
        JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();

        // Table...
        JTable table = getTable();

        // Scroll pane...
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        // Internal frame...
        final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("Test Internal Frame", true, true, true, true);
        internalFrame.setSize(400, 300);
        internalFrame.setLocation(50, 50);
        internalFrame.setVisible(true);

        // Add everything...
        frame.setContentPane(desktopPane);
        desktopPane.add(internalFrame);
        internalFrame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                internalFrame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void runNormalDemo()
    {
        // Frame...
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Normal Demo");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Table...
        JTable table = getTable();

        // Scroll pane...
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();

        // Add everything...
        frame.setContentPane(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                frame.applyComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static JTable getTable()
    {
        final String[] columns = { "test 1", "test 2", "test 3", "test 4" };
        final Object[][] data = { { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, { "1", "2", "3", "4" } };
        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        return table;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT:*

Apologies for the lack of clarity - written in quite a rush.

The issue is that when I reduce the *width* of the table, the 'Normal Demo' (not contained within a JInternalFrame) the horizontal scroll bar starts on the right, where as, doing the same for the 'Internal Frame Demo', the horizontal scroll bar starts on the left.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about minimizing or about reducing window size until ScrollBars show up? Which Java version are you using? I tried your example with Windows and Java 1.6, and both ScrollBars are on the left side. When I remove your `applyComponentOrientation`, both ScrollBars are on the right side.

Comment: @Ed ...Atleast I understood the problem(after a lot fo head scrathcing). it seems like it happens only inside an InternalFrame Though i dont understand how would poisitoning of the crollbar(left/right) would make any problem. I would look in to it nonetheless.

Comment: I still can not reproduce it. Both ScrollBars start at the left... Which Java version do you use?

Comment: @Suraj I would much rather have the first column of the table visible for as long as possible, and only out of view if the user chooses to scroll horizontally; since, in my non-demo code the first few columns are the most important and the remainer are less so. Thanks for looking.

Comment: @Peter Interesting! So I tried this using jdk1.5.0_16 and it is as I originally described - the horizontal scrollbar inside the internal frame starts on the left (incorrect), without the internal frame, it starts on the right (I believe to be correct). However, using jdk1.6.0_10, both horizontal scroll bars start on the left (incorrect)! So the issue gets worse with time...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, with Java 1.6 there does not seem to be a difference in the behaviors of internal and standard frames.

Bug "[JScrollPane ignores ComponentOrientation](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=ffebe57198b0199ba456bf7ace9c?bug_id=4229940)" describes your problem, but it has been fixed long time ago.

Bug "[JScrollPane does not layout properly with RTL (RIGHT_TO_LEFT)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4845945)" is still open and could cause your problem.

I found a solution in [Sun Forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5415339) that made it work for me, although the problem was slightly different. Vertical scrollbar is displayed on the right side instead of the left.

```
scrollPane.setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout() {
    
    @Override
    public void layoutContainer(Container parent) {
        JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) parent;
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(
          ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        super.layoutContainer(parent);
        scrollPane.setComponentOrientation(
          ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }
});
```

The current behavior sounds like a bug to me, since the bug (see above) has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you see, but here is what i see.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3608004/jframe.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3608004/jframe.png)

In both cases the scrollbar is on the left (before and after minimize), and this is the right thing. In Arabic (right-to-left langauge) the default position for scrollbars is on the left